# Return false is not working, but the alert is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When I upload an image with a size greater than 1Mb, the alert is working and the image also uploaded. Can anyone please help me?

```
$(document).on('change', '#images', function(){
    files = this.files;
    size = files[0].size;

    if (size < 1000141) { 
        return true;
        // exit();
        // end;
    }

    alert('Please upload less than 1mb file');
    return false;
    return true;
});

//to show the preview of uploaded image
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        $('#blah').show();
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}

$("#images").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: you wrote return false and return true both after alert ?

Comment: on is a listener so still your onchange would continue as it is. why can't you do the validation before calling the readURL and not as a separate listener.

Comment: `return true` after `return false`

Comment: i changed the return true ,but still it's not working

Comment: Mr kcube can u plz explain that

Comment: now if the image size is greater than 1mb doesn't show the preview, but when submitted it uploaded.may i want to change my controller function

Answer (score -1):

You've got a `return true` after the `return false`. change it as below

```
$(document).on('change', '#images', function(){
    files = this.files;
    size = files[0].size;

    if (size < 1000141) { 
        return true;
        // exit();
        // end;
    }

    alert('Please upload less than 1mb file');
    return false;


 });
//rest of your code
```